# NativeScript Angular - Unable to navigate between sibling views located in different page-router-outlets

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-routing, nativescript-angular

I have this `TabView` component:

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
  <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Item 1'}" name="map"></page-router-outlet>
  <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Item 2'}" name="subscribe"></page-router-outlet>
</TabView>
```

Router config:

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/(map:map//subscribe:subscribe)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'map',
    loadChildren: '~/app/routes/+map/map.module#MapModule',
    outlet: 'map'
  },
  {
    path: 'subscribe',
    loadChildren: '~/app/routes/+subscribe/subscribe.module#SubscribeModule',
    outlet: 'subscribe'
  }
```

In the feature module `SubscribeModule` I have a function which should navigate to the `map` route:

```
// The NativeScript router service
constructor(private router: RouterExtensions) {}

navigate(args) {

  const item = this.items[args.index];

  this.router.navigate(['map'], {
    transition: {
      name: 'slideLeft',
      duration: 300
   }
  });
}
```

But all I keep getting is `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'map'`.

I have also tried the following:

- Navigating to the named outlet with `this.router.navigate([{outlets: {map: 'map'}}]`
- Navigating with `this.router.navigate(['../', 'map'])`
- Navigate using `navigateByUrl`

But they all yield the same result.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I think when you have multiple outlets you have to satisfy the URL that contains segments for all outlets. Refer [template-tab-navigation-ng](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-tab-navigation-ng) for clean examples.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this in any way? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @DanielN. Nope.. :/ I think one solution might be to first change the selectedIndex of the TabView and then try to navigate.. but that would probably break as well..

Comment: Thanks, I will try this in the next few days and let you know if it works. I'll most likely use a Subject inside a service and tie it to the selectedIndex property so it can be changed from any component.

Comment: @DanielN. I can confirm that changing the `selectedIndex` of the `TabView` after navigating works. Just use a service with a subject and trigger it when navigating then you can just subscribe to the subject observable in whatever component your `TabView` is in and change the index accordingly.

Comment: Great to hear, thanks for trying it out. You should post it as an answer and mark it accepted for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

this.router.navigate(["/map"], {
    transition: {
      name: 'slideLeft',
      duration: 300
   }
  });

try adding private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute in component

this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { search: ["map"] } }], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute });

Comment: I have same problem and i solved it using above both approach for details you can look into docs https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation  it might solve your problem

Comment: That gives `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'subscribe'`, which is odd since it's not subscribe I'm trying to navigate to...